# Emit data not coming through to the parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a child emitting an event to the parent, and I can't get the data out of it.

I have to emit for various paginations and tried to get the parent to accept two data fields, but I can't get the output to see it.

```js
//Emit Page Totals
send_pag_totals() {
  this.$emit("pageCount", this.pageCount, this.currentPage);
}
```

```js
//Bind to component on parent
@pageCount="depositsCounts()" 

//log the values
depositsCounts(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

I want to get both the integers from the emitted event, and just console log the output for now.

Comment: Try `@pageCount="depositsCounts"` and `depositsCounts(pageCount, currPage) {`. You will have values passed from child component.